# Disabling automatic teasers

Tags: theme-development, excerpt

I have a custom theme that displays the excerpt:

```
    $data = get_the_excerpt();
    if ($data) echo "<div class='excerpt'>$data</div>";
```

if nothing is entered in the  excerpt field in the post editor, Wordpress [will automatically use the auto-generated teaser](http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt#Excerpt.2C_automatic_excerpt.2C_and_teaser).

I would like to get rid of this behaviour. Is there any way to do so? At the moment, I have to entere a space into the excerpt field of every post to prevent the automatic teaser from showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$post->post_excerpt` instead:

```
// globalize $post, just in case
global $post;
// find out if the post has a defined excerpt
$data = $post->post_excerpt;
// If so, output something
if ($data) echo "<div class='excerpt'>$data</div>";
```

This method will bypass the auto-excerpt generation inherent in `get_the_excerpt()`.

**EDIT**

By popular demand, the same code, using `has_excerpt()`:

```
// find out if the post has a defined excerpt
$data = ( has_excerpt() ? get_the_excerpt() : false );
// If so, output something
if ($data) echo "<div class='excerpt'>$data</div>";
```

Comment: has_excerpt() is a better function to use instead of accessing the global $post directly. Forward compatible and what-not.

Answer (score 0):

A method I use which dosen't require using `global $post;` is to use this snipit right before `the_excerpt()` inside the loop.

```
<?php
if (!has_excerpt()) {
         the_content(); //show the content if no excerpt
 } else {
         the_excerpt(); //else show excerpt
}
?>
```

If you only wanted to show `the_excerpt()` if it existed and not `the_content()` at all you could use:

```
  if(has_excerpt()){
          the_excerpt();
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `global $post`? Anyway, I think what the OP wants is to use the *manual excerpt* (i.e. as entered into the **Excerpt** field on the post-edit screen) if it exists, but also *not display* the auto-generated excerpt if no user-defined excerpt exists.

Comment: @ChipBennett Nothing is _wrong_ persay I just like to offer alternatives. The above code (second example) will not show auto generated excerpts.